# Difference of convex functions for $x/y^2$

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let $f=\frac x{y^2}$ be a positive function defined on the domain $x>0$ and $y>0$.
I want to express $f$ as $g-h$ where both g and h are convex.
Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $$\frac{x}{y^2}=\left(x+\frac1{2y^2}\right)^2-\left(x^2+\frac1{4y^4}\right)$$
easy enough?

Comment: Thanks! What’s the strategy to achieve this in general?

Comment: The set of such functions (differences of convex functions) is closed under basic operations, under certain assumptions. That's all very old, last millenium, like [this article](https://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p09-s.pdf).